# objectForKey not returning anything

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmutabledictionary

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)request:(NSString *)requestString {
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:requestString ofType:@"xml"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    respString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath usedEncoding:nil error:&error];
NSLog(@"Ping xml");
    tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[parser readXMLString:respString]];
    NSLog(@"%@",tempDict);
return tempDict;
}
```

Until there, everything is ok, the NSLog is showing that there are 2 objects and keys in the tempDict.
But then:

```
-(int) authenticateUser {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[self request:@"login"]];
    if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"sessionId0"] isEqualToString:@"-1"] ) {
        //Some code
    }
    else {
        cError = 1;
        NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"sessionId0"]);
        appDelegate.sessionId = [dictionary objectForKey:@"sessionId0"];
    }
    [dictionary release];
    return cError;
}
```

At the last else, where cError is 1, NSLog outputs nil for that object.
(NSLog for the entire dictionary also outputs nil)

Comment: Are you sure `[self request:@"login"]` is not nil? Try NSLog it in `authenticateUser`

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but are you sure you want to allocate a new dictionary for the results instead of just using the dictionary that's returned by [self request:] ?  This won't help your specific question, just for what you're doing here, I don't see why you want to allocate a whole new dictionary and copy the results of request: into it...  For your actual question, maybe you forgot to add the request: method to your interface for this class?

Comment: Your if statement checks for [dictionary objectForKey:@"sessionID0"], but in your else portion you check for [dictionary objectForKey:@"sessionID"]. Is that what you have in your actual code is that a typing error here?

Comment: @Saphrosit Yes i did and it prints the info correctly.
@wallacer Will check, thanks for pointing it out.
@sosborn I corrected it. In my code it correctly checks for sessionId0, I`m sorry for placing wrong information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in your and see what the output is for dict object...

```
-(int) authenticateUser {
NSDictionary* dict = (NSDictionary *)[self request:@"login"];
NSLog(@"Dictionary %@",dict);    

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[self request:@"login"]];
    if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"sessionId0"] isEqualToString:@"-1"] ) {
        //Some code
    }
    else {
        cError = 1;
        NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"sessionId"]);
        appDelegate.sessionId = [dictionary objectForKey:@"sessionId"];
    }
    [dictionary release];
    return cError;
}
```